# Are these three-spoke dovetailing tile tessellations known to geometry? (Animation)

Tags: tiling, tessellations

[Trispokedovetiles Animation Webpage](http://scot.tk/trispokedovetiles/trispokedovetiles.htm)

I've programmed a webpage using Javascript to display an animation which shows a range of different **trispokedovetiles**, each of which can be specified by a "CIRCLE" percentage, which is the ratio as a percent of two parameters -

1. A "HEXAGON" parameter length - always nominally "100%"
2. A "CIRCLE" parameter length - the animation varies this between 100% and 135%, though up to 150% is possible in theory.

So you can specify the "CIRCLE" percentage to specify a particular shape of trispokedovetile.
 
A still image from the animation is attached - showing trispokedovetiles with "CIRCLE" = 125%.

[Still image from trispokedovetile animation, CIRCLE = 125%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbJ0t.png)

I've tested the animation in Chrome and Internet Explorer browsers and it works fine for me.

But it is not working in Firefox for some as yet unknown reason.

Let me know by replying here if you have any other problems with the animation not displaying for you.

I've named the shape

## Trispokedovetile

which is a contraction of "tri-spoke dovetailing tile".

- "tri-spoke" because the shape is similar to a 3-spoke motorcycle
  wheel with three bites taken out of it.
- "dovetailing" because the    tiles interlock like a dovetail joint

But it is quite possible this tile shape is already known to geometry and already has been named.

Do you know if this tessellating tile shape has already been named? If so please do reply to tell me what the name is.

Comment: Works just fine for me. (Firefox 50.0.1.) Also, the tesselation looks nice, and I don't think it has a name yet.

Comment: Update - CNC code to cut tiles I have recently published a new webpage which encourages the possible uses of this shape in engineering by providing a Computer Aided Manufacturing tool which helps to produce Computer Numerical Control programs for an automated laser cutter or other cutting machine. [Trispokedovetiles: CNC code to cut tiles] (http://scot.tk/trispokedovetiles/trispokedovetiles-CNC.htm)